# статический анализатор кода clion подчеркивает компилируемый код, связанный с корутинами с++20

Tags: clion, c++20

Статический анализатор кода cline подчеркивает компилируемый код, связанный с корутинами с++20.
Есть ли возможность исправить это ? В качестве примера, в коде ниже выводится следующая ошибка

> Std::experimental::coroutine_traits type was not found; include
> <experimental/coroutine> before defining a coroutine

Хотя данный код прекрасно компилируется.

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

auto switch_to_new_thread(std::jthread& out) {
    struct awaitable {
        std::jthread* p_out;
        bool await_ready() { return false; }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
            std::jthread& out = *p_out;
            if (out.joinable())
                throw std::runtime_error("Output jthread parameter not empty");
            out = std::jthread([h] { h.resume(); });
            // Potential undefined behavior: accessing potentially destroyed *this
            // std::cout << "New thread ID: " << p_out->get_id() << '\n';
            std::cout << "New thread ID: " << out.get_id() << '\n'; // this is OK
        }
        void await_resume() {}
    };
    return awaitable{&out};
}

struct task{
    struct promise_type {
        task get_return_object() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
    };
};

task resuming_on_new_thread(std::jthread& out) {
    std::cout << "Coroutine started on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    co_await switch_to_new_thread(out);
    // awaiter destroyed here
    std::cout << "Coroutine resumed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::jthread out;
    resuming_on_new_thread(out);
}
```

Comment: cline? может все таки clang? а если с консоли запустить анализ, находит? clang-check с консоли что показывет?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это clang-tyde встроен как статический анализатор в clion. Я пользуюсь gcc-10, он не выдает ошибок при компиляции. @KoVadim

Comment: вот вот.  gcc поддерживает корутины, поэтому и компилируется. А clang, а с ним и анализатор - не совсем (https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html - написано Partial). Что делать? забить и жить дальше, забыть  о анализаторе и жить дальше, забыть  о корутинах и жить дальше, дописать в кланг поддержку корутин и получить благодарности от сообщества

Comment: @KoVadim, понял)